# linking web application's backend in python and frontend in flutter

Tags: python, flutter, flutter-web

I am making a CRM web application. I am planning to do its backend in python(because I only know that language better) and I have a friend who uses flutter for frontend. Is it possible to link these two things(flutter and python backend)? If yes how can it be done...and if no what are the alternatives I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  `$.ajax()` method in HTML pages and then used `request.POST['variable_name_used_in_ajax()']` in the views.py

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most commonly used would be [JSON-RPC over HTTP](https://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-over-http.html) (more commonly, and incorrectly, referred to as a REST API). I'd suggest looking into OpenAPI / Swagger

Language choice doesn't matter. Import an HTTP client in Flutter, write a web server in Django, Flask, Quart, etc (your pick) and link the two using HTTP. That's all that's needed.

I'm sure gRPC could be used as well, which would allow you to potentially generate any Python server and Dart client code for flutter to import

Answer (score 0):

Yes you both can access same Django rest framework Backend. Try searching for rest API using Django rest framework and you are good to go.

Other alternatives are Firebase or creating rest API with PHP.

You would need to define API endpoints for different functions of your app like login,register etc.

Django rest framework works well with Flutter. I have tried it. You could also host it in Heroku

Use http package in flutter to communicate with the Django server.

Comment: Why php? OP wanted python

Comment: And I'd suggest Serverless or lambda over heroku

Comment: I just wanted him to know about other options in case.